# How to Call stored procedure function in airflow using PostgresOperator

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, airflow, mwaa

I am not sure about how to call stored procedure in airflow operator-
eg. **Stored Procedure** is- Call `goal.dba.sp_ctrl_calendar()`

My code-

```
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
sp_ctrl_calendar = PostgresOperator(
        task_id = 'sp_ctrl_calendar',
        sql = 'goal.dba.sp_ctrl_calendar(); end;',
        postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
        autocommit = True)
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is-

```
sql_command_1 = 'call goal.dba.sp_ctrl_calendar()'
sp_ctrl_calendar = PostgresOperator(
    task_id = 'sp_ctrl_calendar',
    sql = sql_command_1,
    postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
    autocommit = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

in postgresql ( or redshift) to call a proc , command is `call procname`
so your sql command shoulld look like this:

```
from airflow.operators.postgres_operator import PostgresOperator
sp_ctrl_calendar = PostgresOperator(
        task_id = 'sp_ctrl_calendar',
        sql = 'call goal.dba.sp_ctrl_calendar',
        postgres_conn_id = 'redshift',
        autocommit = True)
```